# Why Spring MVC 4 and Hystrix integration not working without Spring boot API?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, netflix, hystrix

Before I start let me tell that I'm trying to integrate Spring MVC 4 application with Hystrix(i.e. using hystrix-javanica for full annotation support). Below is my piece of code....
**Configuration class:**

```
@Configuration
public class BeanConfig {

    @Bean
    public HystrixCommandAspect hystrixCommandAspect() {
        return new HystrixCommandAspect();
    }
}
```

**Hystrix enabled service class**

```
@Service(value="userRepository")
public class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepository{

    @Override
    @HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "failService",
                    commandProperties = {
                            @HystrixProperty(name = "execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds", value = "500")
                    },
                    threadPoolProperties = {
                            @HystrixProperty(name = "coreSize", value = "30"),
                            @HystrixProperty(name = "maxQueueSize", value = "101"),
                            @HystrixProperty(name = "keepAliveTimeMinutes", value = "2"),
                            @HystrixProperty(name = "queueSizeRejectionThreshold", value = "15"),
                            @HystrixProperty(name = "metrics.rollingStats.numBuckets", value = "12"),
                            @HystrixProperty(name = "metrics.rollingStats.timeInMilliseconds", value = "1440")
                    })
    public User getUserByAuthentication(String username) {
        throw new RuntimeException("delegately throwing exception");//intentionally throwing exception to check fallback service
    }

    @HystrixCommand
    public User failService(String username) {
        System.out.println("in the fallback service");
        return new User(username);
    }
}
```

**And this is conrtroller class**

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("userRepository")
private UserRepository userRepository;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String init(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    System.out.println("in controller getting value as :" + userRepository.getUserByAuthentication("testvalue"));
    return "some page";     
}
```

Now, when I'm running this application the exception is getting thrown but after that no fallback service is getting called. I've tried to debug but after the exception the workflow is getting stopped.
Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: add `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` to your configuration.

Comment: Working like a charm.....thanks a ton @M. Deinum

Comment: Worked for me too. Thanks @M.Deinum

Comment: @M.Deinum Please write that as an answer, not as a comment.

Answer (score 3):

When using AspectJ with Spring (and without Spring Boot) you will need to tell Spring to do something with the `@Aspect` annotated beans it detects. By default they are simply ignored.

To do so you will need to add `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` on your configuration (or `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />` in XML). This will instruct Spring to apply the `@Aspect` annotated beans it detects in the context.

All of this is quite extensively described in the [Enabling @AspectJ Support](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aspectj-support) section of the Spring Reference guide.